# iPhone Add support for Backgrounder

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to create a app for my personal use that uses Backgrounder.
Are there any prerequisite that the app can be used by Backgrounder as it refuses to put my app in background.

I have seen the wiki and Google code page of Backgrounder and it states "If you wish to run a non-AppStore 3rd-party application in the background, it is suggested that you contact the author of the application and request that proper background support be added. "

But there is no additional info about it... and mailing list is ... where ? Joining the group is also a mystery.

What constitutes a "proper background support"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see it http://code.google.com/p/iphone-backgrounder/wiki/Documentation

Hope this helps.

A.

Comment: Seen it... but it states "If you wish to run a non-AppStore 3rd-party application in the background, it is suggested that you contact the author of the application and request that proper background support be added. " 
But there is no additional info about it... and mailing list is ... where ?